# checkbox selected using jquery and id

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to select the ckeckbox using jquery and adding the class.

Checkbox Code :

```
<label>
  <span class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="is_global" id="check">
  </span>
</label>
```

In my code. if i want to select checkbox than add class `selected` in span tag. like this :

```
<label>
  <span class="custom-checkbox selected">
    <input type="checkbox" name="is_global" id="check">
  </span>
</label>
```

So my questiona is how to add class selected using jquery with id `check`.

i have tried following. but not working.

```
$("#check span['custom-checkbox']").addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

Select element using id and get it's parent using [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method.

```
$('#check').parent().addClass('selected')
```

---

Or use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector to get element which cotains any particular elemnt.

```
$('.custom-checkbox:has(#check)').addClass('selected')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#check").parent().addClass('selected');
```

or

```
$("#check").parents('.custom-checkbox').addClass('selected');
```

https://api.jquery.com/parent/

https://api.jquery.com/parents/

try something like this

```
$('#check').change(function() {
    $(this).parents('.custom-checkbox').toggleClass('selected', $(this).is(':checked'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :

```
$("#check span['custom-checkbox']").addClass('selected');
```

By this :

```
$('#check').change(function() {
    $check = $(this);
    if ($check.is(':checked')) {
        $("span.custom-checkbox").addClass('selected');
    }
}
```

Because `.custom-checkbox` is a class and you want to test if the input is checked before adding the class.

**Source :** https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/dHZS9/

Answer (score 0):

try this

$("#check").parent().addClass('selected');

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("check").checked = true;
```

Try this instead of the last statement whenever you wish it should be checked.

Comment: Not Working ... It will apply to checkbox. In my case i will hide my checkbox. so that css will apply to checkbox